# Can we rename the complexity tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The questions tagged [complexity](/questions/tagged/complexity) seem to mostly be asking about complexity theory, as is its tag wiki description.

I propose renaming the tag to [complexity-theory](/questions/tagged/complexity-theory), mostly because I have [complexity](/questions/tagged/complexity) under the likes section on my Careers 2.0 profile and I think that could be misunderstood.

Comment: It would be... •_•) ( •_•)>⌐■-■
(⌐■_■) [quite _complex_](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/106/887/backpain-1292835351.jpg).

Comment: This is entirely because I was into theoretical CS in college, but what other meaning did you intend to have? I just assumed that it was only ever used for complexity theory questions (or maybe if someone didn't know the runtime of something)

Comment: @DennisMeng I don't intend for `complexity` to have any other meaning (or even exist as a tag anymore). It's just more clear what you mean on a Careers profile when you like `complexity-theory` rather than just `complexity`.

Comment: Personally used to saying "complexity" as shorthand, but I guess that's fair.

Comment: @Dennis what's the complexity of typing complexity?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Linear I suppose, like most other words.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know is it impossible to rename a tag except for a moderator. You could try to retag all questions or to create a tag synonym. The last one would require that you have as far I remember that you have 5 upvotes in this new tag.